# Implicit conversion of data from date to timestamp(6) with local timezone in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp

I would like to know if oracle really implicitly converts the existing data in the table when I convert the column from data type date to timestamp(6) with local time zone.

Example
Existing date: 
04-MAY-10   10:23:53 --> date is processed during DST is on

when the column is converted from date to timestamp(6) with local time zone:
04-MAY-10 11.23.53.000000000 AM  --> there is 1 hour difference

Does oracle really do this?
Do we have a solution for the existing data to not be modified during the changing of the column type?

Thanks,
Jerald

Comment: How are you converting it? Do mean changing the table's column type, or just as part of a query? It might be useful to include the time zone region in your formatted value so you can see it's DST. But showing your existing code/query will help us explain what you are doing wrong.

Comment: And also, what does `select dbtimezone, sessiontimezone from dual` tell you?

Comment: Hi Alex, it is just changing the table's column type. dbtimezone: +01:00 sessiontimezone: CET

Comment: It is just a simple query I used: --- alter table gje_test modify col1 timestamp(6) with local time zone;